# How to change name separator in bibtex-generated bibliography to a different language

Tags: bibtex, languages

When I run BibTeX, it generates in entries with several authors something like this:
`Winfried Just and Martin Weese.`
If you write a text in a different language, I suppose it is more customary to translate *and* to your language.

In my case I use `cslatex` and I have to change the entries manually in the bbl-file to
`Winfried Just a Martin Weese.`
if I want *a* instead of *and*.

> - Is there a way to do this automatically, without manual modification of the bbl-file?

Comment: Are you taking about the input (in the `.bib` file) or the output (in your document)?

Comment: I meant `.bbl`, sorry for my mistake - it is corrected now.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, over all. Which BibTeX style (`.bst` file) do you use?

Comment: Most frequently I use plain or [shorter.bst](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~markey/BibTeX/short/shorter.bst), which I obtained from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.text.tex/QWG2F-KhvXM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "and" is usually coded explicitly in the `.bst` bibliographic style file that you are using. As far as I know (but perhaps someone knows if `biblatex` can do that), there is no other option (unless there is something specific to `cslatex`) to change it than going into the `.bst` file, finding the macro which puts the "and" string on the stack, and replacing manually "and" with whatever you like. Then you have a new bibliographic style that you can call in the usual way in your `.tex` file (`\bibliographystyle{myfile}`).

By the way, there are other items that you may want to localize in the same manner ("editors", "chapter", "volume", "pages",...)

Comment: It seems to be working. I've modified `FUNCTION {format.names}` in the bst file, and the behavior changed. (I have to admit that I did this without much understanding what I am doing.)

Comment: When you want to create a new `.bst` file, you can always use the `makebst` utility to avoid going into the BibTeX language, but when only small modifications are needed, it is usually not complicated to modify directly the `.bst` file. In any case, this manual is a valuable help: http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~markey/BibTeX/doc/ttb_en.pdf

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure there is a `biblatex` solution to this problem, although I've never used it myself..