# Doesn't write the full last name of third author

Tags: bibtex

I have some trouble with my literature directory. It doesn't show the full name of the third author. It only shows:

> Hairer, E. und Lubich, C. u. W. G.

But I want to see:

> Hairer, E., Lubich, C. und Wanner, G.

My code looks like following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}  
\begin{document}
     \bibliography{BIB}
\end{document}
```

And in my Bib the code is

```
@book{hairer2002geometric,
 title={Geometric Numerical Integration: Structure-Preserving Algorithms for Ordinary Differential Equations},
author={Hairer, E., Lubich, C. und Wanner, G.},
series={Springer Series in Computational Mathematics},
year={2002},
volume={31},
 publisher={Springer},
 address={Berlin}     
}
```

Comment: `author={Hairer, E. and Lubich, C. and Wanner, G.}` is the correct syntax

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I write it in German, that's why I need 'und' between the authors. How can I change the and to 'und'?

Comment: @little_miss_sunshine The BibTeX database format _requires_ `and` between entries in the _input_: this is nothing to do with what gets printed for 'and' in the output.

Comment: This seems related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70799/how-to-change-name-separator-in-bibtex-generated-bibliography-to-a-different-lan and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17155/changing-the-language-of-an-amsrefs-generated-bibliography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I change the 'and' to 'und'?

If you want to stick with BibTeX and the `chicago` bibliography style, while also getting the conjunction between authors to print as "`und`" rather than as "`and`", you may want to proceed as follows:

- Locate the file `chicago.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and name it, say, `mychicago.bst`. (Don't edit an original file directly.)
- Open `mychicago.bst` in your favorite text editor. (The editor you use to edit your .tex files will do fine.)
- Find and replace all five [5] instances of `" and "` with, you guessed it, `" und "`.
- Save the file `mychicago.bst`, either in the directory where your main .tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by TeX/BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, you will probably need to update TeX's filename database.
- Start using the newly created bibliography style by issuing the command `\bibliographystyle{mychicago}`. The first time you use a new bibliography style, it's usually a good idea to blow away all temporary and auxiliary files and then run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully synchronize all cross-references.

As others have already pointed out, `and` is a BibTeX keyword that's used to separate the authors in an `author` field. Thus, be sure to write either

```
author={Hairer, E. and Lubich, C. and Wanner, G.}
```

or

```
author={E. Hairer and C. Lubich and G. Wanner}
```

With these modifications to `mychicago.bst` in place, this is what you'd get from the entry in question:

[image]

Note that "Chicago" style inverts the surname and first name's initial only for the first author; subsequent authors' names are set as `First-name-initial. Surname`.

Comment: sounds perfect. but I can't find chicago.bst. The only thing I have with chicago are:chicago.tmp, biblatex-chicago.tmp.

Comment: @little_miss_sunshine -- If you open a terminal (aka command line) window and type `kpsewhich chicago.bst` and hit return, what answer do you get? If all else fails, you could [download it from the CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/chicago).

Comment: it even finds something.it says 'C:/users/.../Roaming/Miktex/2.9/... But if I open C/users/... there is no folder Roaming.

Comment: I found it. It was in an hidden folder.

Comment: It works with the 'und' now. Thank you sooooo much.

Comment: @little_miss_sunshine - Very glad to learn that you located the file and that things are working now. :-)

Answer (score 5):

With that BibTeX entry you get *many* errors:

```
Too many commas in name 1 of "Hairer, E., Lubich, C. und Wanner, G." for entry hairer2002geometric
while executing---line 1563 of file chicago.bst
```

and this is repeated 20 times.

The correct syntax is

```
author={Hairer, E. and Lubich, C. and Wanner, G.}
```

Authors should be separated by the keyword `and`; each author is `Surname, Name` or `Name Surname` (the first format is usually preferred).

I suggest you to switch to `biblatex`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{hairer2002geometric,
  title={Geometric Numerical Integration: 
         Structure-Preserving Algorithms 
         for Ordinary Differential Equations},
  author={Hairer, E. and Lubich, C. and Wanner, G.},
  series={Springer Series in Computational Mathematics},
  year={2002},
  volume={31},
  publisher={Springer},
  address={Berlin}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The usage of `filecontents*` is just for making the example selfcontained. In the argument to `\addbibresource` you should insert the actual name of your BibTeX database (ending with `.bib`).

Many customizations are possible.

[image]

Comment: The comment  \printbibliography   doesn't work. If I use it like your code, then the literature directory doesn't show upt at all.

Comment: @little_miss_sunshine You have to use Biber rather than BibTeX