# Cannot parse bibliography items in biber

Tags: biblatex

I am experiencing a rather weird issue. I am using some citations in a document and surprisingly some items are not parsed. My code is

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{cite.bib}

@article{Chiari,
    author    = "M. Chiari, L. Giuntini, P.A. Mando, N. Taccetii",
    title     = "Proton elastic scattering cross-section on boron from 0.5 to 3.3 MeV",
    journal   = "Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Physics Research Section B: Beam Interactions with Materials and Atoms",
    volume    = "184",
    number    = "3",
    pages     = "309-318",
    year      = "2001",
    month     = "November",
hyphenation={english}

}

@article{Mayer,
title = "The $^{11}B\left(p,\alpha_0\right)^8Be$ nuclear reaction and $^{11}B(p,p)^{11}B$ backscattering cross sections for analytical purposes ",
journal = "Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Physics Research Section B: Beam Interactions with Materials and Atoms ",
volume = "143",
number = "3",
pages = "244 - 252",
year = "1998",
note = "",
issn = "0168-583X",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0168-583X(98)00383-8",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168583X98003838",
author = "M. Mayer and A. Annen and W. Jacob and S. Grigull",
hyphenation={english}
}

@article{Rihet,
title = "States in $^{12}C$ from resonant proton scattering ",
journal = "Journal de physique ",
volume = "38",
number = "1",
pages = "17 - 19",
year = "1977",
% note = "",
issn = "0168-583X",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/jphys:0197700380101700",
url = "http://jphys.journaldephysique.org/articles/jphys/abs/1977/01/jphys_1977__38_1_17_0/jphys_1977__38_1_17_0.html",
author = "Y. Rihet, A. Genoux-Lubain, H. Beaumevieille, R. Seltz, C. Gerardin,  D. Magnac-Valette ",
hyphenation={english}

}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{cite.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\greektext#1\latintext}

\begin{document} 
το ενεργειακό και γωνιακό εύρος(\cite[\eng{Chiari}]{Chiari}) καλύπτουν για την γωνία των $120^\circ$ τις ενέργειες $2250,2800\;keV$ για το
$^{11}Β$ (\cite[\eng{Mashkarov}]{Mashkarov}, \cite[\eng{Dejneko}]{Dejneko}) και όλο το ενεργειακό εύρος  για το $^{10}Β$
(\cite[\eng{Overley}]{Overley}). στην ενέργεια των $3300keV$(\cite[\eng{Rihet}]{Rihet}). Τέλος, λόγ $2250\;keV$(\cite[\eng{Mayer}]{Mayer}).
Η επιλογή των εν λ \cite[\eng{Mayer}]{Mayer} και \cite[\eng{Chiari}]{Chiari}, οι οποίες είναι πειραματικές, η απόδειξη της μη έντονης 
γωνιακής εξάρτησης φαίνεται από τα δεδομένα του \cite[\eng{Chiari}]{Chiari}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and my output is

[image]

My compilation process is

1. `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex`
2. `biber file`
3. `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex`

Any idea on why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: This is a VFAQ (very frequently asked question): `author = "M. Chiari and L. Giuntini and P.A. Mando and N. Taccetii",` Names must be joined by the `and` keyword.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149852/doesnt-write-the-full-last-name-of-third-author and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123600/latex-doesnt-recognize-et-al-in-the-bibliography

Comment: @egreg : Thank's for your comments! Indeed adding `and` fixed partially the issue, but it doesn't fix the entries that are not in the `.bib`. For instance I would exept *[Dejneo,;]* for a code `\cite[\eng{Dejneko}]{Dejneko}`...

Comment: I see no `Dejneko` entry. Besides the fact that the definitions of `\eng` and `\greek` are wrong.

Comment: Why are they wrong?

Comment: I see, correctly, “([1, Chiari])” because the bib entry is present. Since no `Dejneko` or `Mashkarov` entry is in the MWE, the output shows just the missing keys. The correct form should be `\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textlatin{#1}}` and `\newcommand{\greek}[1]{\textgreek{#1}}`

Comment: I see... I cannot understand why the deffinition is wrong, however I will modify it!